# an algorithm for determining a consistent coding between two series of codes

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-science

I have a problem where I am trying to use a crosswalk to match code `A` with code `B` in a dataset. For instance, these could be industry codes in 1990 and 1991, where the census changed how they coded the industries. If I can create a harmonized code, I can use this code to track the same industries (or new groups of industries, if necessary) through time. They provide a cross walk which would look like the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
[0,0],
[1,2],
[1,3],
[2,4],
[3,4],
[4,5],
[4,6],
[5,5],
[10,11],
[10,13],
[11,11]
], columns=list('AB'))

df
     A   B
0    0   0
1    1   2
2    1   3
3    2   4
4    3   4
5    4   5
6    4   6
7    5   5
8   10  11
9   10  13
10  11  11
```

So my desired output will be a new column that defines non-overlapping codes in both `A` and `B`. For instance, consider the desired results below:

```py
     A   B    C
0    0   0  0.0
1    1   2  1.0
2    1   3  1.0
3    2   4  2.0
4    3   4  2.0
5    4   5  3.0
6    4   6  3.0
7    5   5  3.0
8   10  11  4.0
9   10  13  4.0
10  11  11  4.0
```

I've started to answer the problem by getting the easy part done first. These are the (one to many) `1:m` and (many to one) `m:1` matches which I can simply assign a common value.

```py
sizesA = df.groupby('A').size()
sizesB = df.groupby('B').size()
df['sizeA'] = df['A'].map(sizesA)
df['sizeB'] = df['B'].map(sizesB)

df['C'] = np.nan

next_v = 0

# 1:m matching

for a in df[df.sizeA>=1].A.unique():
    if df[df.A==a]['sizeB'].max()==1:
        df['C'] = np.where(df['A']==a, next_v, df['C'])
        next_v += 1

# m:1 matching

for b in df[df.sizeB>1].B.unique():
    if df[df.B==b]['sizeA'].max()==1:
        df['C'] = np.where(df['B']==b, next_v, df['C'])
        next_v += 1

df
     A   B  sizeA  sizeB    C
0    0   0      1      1  0.0
1    1   2      2      1  1.0
2    1   3      2      1  1.0
3    2   4      1      2  2.0
4    3   4      1      2  2.0
5    4   5      2      2  NaN
6    4   6      2      1  NaN
7    5   5      1      2  NaN
8   10  11      2      2  NaN
9   10  13      2      1  NaN
10  11  11      1      2  NaN
```

The problem is the (many to many) `m:m` matches. I can't seem to think of a good way to tackle this, and my guess is it is a computationally hard problem to solve. Note that I could just assign the remaining values above a single code, but this would miss the fact that I can partition them into two different codes and still preserve consistency.

Also, let me know if you have any suggestions for the title.

Answer (score 0):

Does C need to start at 0 or can it start at 1?  I simply subtracted 1 so you could start at 0.  You could tweak it for your needs.

Using cumcount and cumsum should make it easier.

```
df['C'] = ((df.groupby('A').cumcount()==0) & (df.groupby('B').cumcount()==0)).cumsum()-1

print(df)

print(df)

     A   B  C
0    0   0  0
1    1   2  1
2    1   3  1
3    2   4  2
4    3   4  2
5    4   5  3
6    4   6  3
7    5   5  3
8   10  11  4
9   10  13  4
10  11  11  4
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me when I ran it on my larger, actual crosswalk. I'll need some time to give a better reason as to why/under what circumstances it fails. But in any case, I think I found an algorithm that works. I'll post that too. But if a one-liner works that'd be great.

Comment: No worries I am glad you found a solution that works.  I am curious, where did it go run, i am wondering if i misunderstood the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a solution. Maybe not that elegant though.

```py
ungrouped = df['A'].unique().tolist()
Anew = pd.Series(index=sorted(df['A'].unique()))
Bnew = pd.Series(index=sorted(df['B'].unique()))

g = 0

Avals = [ungrouped[0]]

while True:
    Bvals = df[df['A'].isin(Avals)].B.unique().tolist()

    Acheck = df[df['B'].isin(Bvals)].A.unique().tolist()

    if set(Acheck) == set(Avals):
        Anew.loc[Avals] = g
        Bnew.loc[Bvals] = g
        g += 1
        ungrouped = [a for a in ungrouped if a not in Avals]
        if len(ungrouped) == 0:
            break
        Avals = [ungrouped[0]]
    else:
        Avals = Acheck

df['C'] = df['A'].map(Anew)
df
     A   B    C
0    0   0  0.0
1    1   2  1.0
2    1   3  1.0
3    2   4  2.0
4    3   4  2.0
5    4   5  3.0
6    4   6  3.0
7    5   5  3.0
8   10  11  4.0
9   10  13  4.0
10  11  11  4.0
```